# Parametrize using a template parameter as a parameter to a lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I want to be able to have some functor as a parameter to a function.

The functor's parameter is supposed to be templated so I can call other functions that depend on it's type.

Here's what I have so far:

```
using namespace std;
template<typename T, typename PredT>
void foo(PredT pred)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        std::function<void(T)> predImpl(pred);
        T t{};
        predImpl(t);
    }
}


template<typename T>
void foo2(std::function<void(T)> func)
{
    for(size_t i=0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        T t{}; //there's obviously other logic that produces those;
        func(t);
    }
}

int main()
{     
    //foo([](int x) {cout << x << '\n';}); //error: no matching function for call to 'foo(main()::<lambda(int)>)
    // foo([](int x) {cout << x << '\n';}); doesn't work  error: no matching function for call to 'foo(main()::<lambda(int)>)' 
    foo2(std::function<void(int)>([](int x) {cout << x << '\n';})); // syntax is ugly, requires an explicit conversion to std::function

}
```

I would basically want to deduce the `T` based on the parameter to the lambda but I have no idea if that is possible.

The solution using the explicit `std::function` conversion works but it's cumbersome and kind of looses the convenience of just using a lambda.

Comment: problem is argument deduction. template cant deduce `T` based on this template definition and usage. Here is [simple fix](https://godbolt.org/z/5K8tXt). Now questions is it possible to deduce `T` from `PredT`? I don't think so.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid having to mention the specific type, but sounds like that cannot be deduced, would you happen to know which rule fails that scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to support generic lambdas, you can do something like this:

```
template <typename C, typename R, typename T>
T detectParameterType(R (C::*)(T));
template <typename C, typename R, typename T>
T detectParameterType(R (C::*)(T) const);

template<typename PredT>
void foo(PredT pred)
{
    using T = decltype(detectParameterType(&PredT::operator()));
    T t{};
    pred(t);
}
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/RJX64030)

Generic lambdas can take parameters of any type, so naturally it's impossible to deduce the parameter type - there's no single type to deduce.